# .bashrc custom secondary password and SCP is not working, (SSH secondary password)

Tags: linux, bash, scp

For "some purpose" I have added a script in the `~/.bashrc` to prompt for a secondary password and its serves my purpose. But, there is only one small issue is there.

When I `scp` to the server, It fails due to my custom script in the `~/.bashrc`
The error I am getting when doing a `scp` is "stdin: is not a tty"

I invoke `sh second_pass.sh` from the `~/.bashrc`

Content of `second_pass.sh`:

```
trapeze ()  {
    printf "Trying to kill me!!" }

trap trapeze SIGINT

while true; do echo "Please enter the password:" read -s password

if [[ -z "$password" ]] ; then
    continue ; fi

hash="$(echo -n "$password" | md5sum )" password=`echo "$hash" | awk '{print $1}'`

if [ "$password" == "a359c98e8c05feaf91bdb8cfc7dd6b" ] then
    exit ; else
    echo "WRONG!!!" fi done
```

the result is, when I do `scp` is

```
stdin: is not a tty
Please enter the password:
```

and then `scp` fails.

I want to use the `scp` & also keep the password prompting script in my `~/.bashrc`.
How can I achieve it ?

Comment: I think you can't - the `scp` protocol wants standard input/output for itself, so even if you allocated a TTY (`-o RequestTTY=force`) it would fail later, and if it were using SFTP inside you probably wouldn't have the error now. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440287/scp-doesnt-work-when-echo-in-bashrc) for a similar failure. Note though that *what you're doing doesn't actually provide any security whatsoever*, so if you're expecting that to be real then consider another approach.

Comment: Note that your password is now know for anyone reading this page.

Comment: how any one know my password ? It is in MD5 and more over, I deleted some char from that.

Comment: @Mani: Brute force, rainbow tables, online services, crack farms. Your edit is visible for anyone clicking the *edited* link below your post. One can ask mods to remove such history in special cases, but it would be of little help. It has long since been cached and copied to various servers around the world. Look for example here: http://unixlinuxcm.blogspot.com/2015/01/bashrc-custom-secondary-password-and.html

Comment: After a quick search. You could for example try your hash here: http://www.md5online.org/

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
 while true ; do echo ...
```

by

```
 while tty -s ; do echo ...
```

This will disable double password checking.

This might not be you intend.

Now if you keep to your double password strategy, the only choice left is to pull the file with `scp` once your are loggon (and twice identified), this depend on the plateform the file is comming from.